# Centered text in Tkinter GRID

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I have a problem with grid manager in Python Tkinter.
I was add a Frame and labels inside it appeared in center instead of left top.
What is the problem with my code?
Thanks.

[GUIImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uafxL.png)

```
from tkinter import *


class PacijentGUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.napraviGUI()

def napraviGUI(self):
    #Listbox
    self.__pacijentiListbox = Listbox(self,width=35, height=15)
    self.__pacijentiListbox.grid(row=0,column = 0,sticky = E)


    #Frame
    panelZaPrikaz = Frame(self, borderwidth = 2, relief = "ridge", padx=100,pady = 78)
    panelZaPrikaz.grid(row=0,column = 1,sticky = E)

    #Labels in frame
    Label(panelZaPrikaz,text = "LBO: ").grid(row = 0,column = 0)
    Label(panelZaPrikaz,text = "Ime: ").grid(row = 1,column = 0)
    Label(panelZaPrikaz,text="Prezime: ").grid(row = 2,column = 0)
    Label(panelZaPrikaz,text = "Datum rodjenja: ").grid(row = 3,column=0)



def main():
    app = PacijentGUI()
    app.geometry("800x600")
    app.title('Evidencija')
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're explicitly telling the items to stick to the left side of their column. Have your tried removing that bit of code?

Comment: I tried and didn't help.

Comment: You're going to need to create a [mcve]. I don't think there's anyway we can help with just a few lines of code out of context.

Comment: I edited code with minimal reproducible example.